# Can I stop game lag in 7 Days to Die?

Tags: ps4, 7-days-to-die

While playing 7 Days to Die on my PS4, it will occasionally lag/freeze when attempting to do something. It can be when I'm building, collecting materials, etc... but it always seems to happen at the worst point, whenever I collect some murky water.

Now since the game lagged and I accidentally pushed the L2 button twice, I collected and drank the murky water which in turn gave me dysentery. Well not me, but my character in the game.

Is there a setting in either my PS4 or in the game itself that can help with the lagging?

I don't seem to have this problem with any other game I play. And I'm not playing online right now, since I'm new to the game I'm playing solo until I get better before going online. So I know it's not a networking lag issue.

Comment: How much free space is on your PS4? One time I had over 100GB of free space and everything worked fine except for Shadow of Mordor which ran cutscenes at about 0.5 fps until I cleared up my storage. Maybe something similar is happening to you?

Comment: @Vemonus I would have to check, I think I only have like 6 - 8 games installed so I wouldn't think that much space is being taken up. Unfortunately at work right now so I can't see until I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently they're working on the lag issue.  It's an issue everyone is experiencing.  It's not your PS4 causing the issue.  Have to live with it until they fix it.